# UITableViewCell 3 Time Selected Change Background Color on Multiple Selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, selected

I have 5 rows. Background color will change when 3 or more is selected.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let backgroundView = UIView()
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = YOUR_COLOR_HERE
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
    return cell
}
```

These code change bacground color. But I want the background color to change when 3 or more is selected.

How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated code

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
var numberTaps = 0
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //code cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if numberTaps == 3
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    numberTaps += 1
    if numberTaps == 3
    {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: But this code all change rows. I want to only change select rows

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should add configuration for both states, whether tableviewCell meets the `isTapsEnough` condition or not.

```
var numberOfTaps: Int = 0

var isTapsEnough: Bool { retrun numberOfTaps >= 3  }

func tap() {
  self.numberOfTaps += 1
  if self.isTapsEnough { 
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
  cell.contentView.backgroundColor = self.isTapsEnough ? .yellow : .clear
  return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  self.tap()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to start

```
var SelectedIndexpath = [IndexPath]()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if SelectedIndexpath.contains(indexPath){
        SelectedIndexpath.remove(at: SelectedIndexpath.index(of: indexPath)!)
    }else{
        SelectedIndexpath.append(indexPath)
    }
        tableView.reloadData()
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if SelectedIndexpath.count >= 3  && SelectedIndexpath.contains(indexPath){
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
    }else{
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    cell.accessoryType = SelectedIndexpath.contains(indexPath) ? .checkmark : .none
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing the indexPaths of the selected cells in a separate property when UITableView provides `indexPathsForSelectedRows`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this example, although code syntax may be wrong.

```
var indexPaths: [IndexPath] = [IndexPath]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.contains(indexPath) ?? false {
       tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
       return nil
    }
    indexPaths.append(indexPath)
    return indexPath
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    for (index, value) in indexPaths.enumerated() {
        if value == indexPath {
            indexPaths.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //code cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if indexPaths.count >= 3
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to make adjustments in the background color, etc is in `willDisplayCell` and observe `indexPathsForSelectedRows`:

(disclaimer: typed in browser, not tested in Xcode)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows.count >= 3 && tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows.contains(indexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = .red    // or change the backgroundView color
    }
    else {
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear  // or whatever color you want
    }
}
```